# Export C++ Package with Abstract and Normal Classes to Python

Tags: python, c++, export, abstract-class

I would like to export **a lot** of abstract and normal classes from C++ to Python. It is essentially a whole package coded in C++ and would like it to be ran in Python. Instead of individually wrapping each classes, is there a way to easily wrap them and have them work in Python?

Comment: Hello. What do you mean by export. Do you want to build a python module (pyc) from C++ or do you want to write the python equivalent of you c++ abstract class?

Comment: Hi @Jean-MarcVolle I'd like to export the class to then be able to use them in python

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thanks @AMC. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[boost python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python?action=show&redirect=BoostPython) and [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) allow you to "export" C++ classes as python object.
Both propose similar approaches based on templates. Pybind11 solution is said to be easier to use. If you use Microsoft toolchain, you can refer to this page to see how to design/build python bindings using pybind11:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you know if I have say, a whole package coded in C++ with many classes and abstract classes, if there is a way to "easily" wrap them all at once instead of wrapping them individually?

Comment: I am not aware of a tool that would automatically do the bindings for you however, if your c++ code uses strong enough coding rules you might be able to script a good part of the wrapping. You could most probably create your own templates on top of the pybind11 ones to minimize the amount of code you have to manually write for each of the c++ classes. Another approach is to parse your headers and generate the wrapping code through a script (regexp is your friend!)

Answer (score 1):

Using cppyy (http://cppyy.org) is an option, and about as automatic as it gets: just load the headers and the libraries. If there are truly a huge number of headers, then you can precompile them. Instantiation of templates and cross-inheritance is done dynamically, at run-time, so do not need to be prepared.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible if you use for example pybind11 to wrap your C++ code. But you need to create a wrapper class around it.
There is an example of precisely this [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html)

SWIG is another possibility. This one makes use of your existing C++ header file. See [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html) and go down to section 6.6.3 for forcing abstract class constructor to be created using the %feature for customization

```
%feature("notabstract") YourClassHere
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you know if I have say, a whole package coded in C++ with many classes and abstract classes, if there is a way to "easily" wrap them all at once instead of wrapping them individually?

Comment: @mikanim I have included SWIG in my answer. You can just reuse your existing header file.